# How to group legends in Ant Design Line Chart?

Tags: reactjs, antd

By default, Ant Design Line Chart will have toggleable legends depending on the `category` I have in my array of data below. How can I group this legends together so that I can toggle multiple line at the same time? For example, I want to have a legend of `95% CI`, so when I click on it, it will toggle both `upper_95` and `lower_95` category.

My data:

```js
const data = [
    {"date":"2021-11-17", "category":"upper_95", "value":23.87625},
    {"date":"2021-11-17", "category":"lower_95", "value":20.32322},
    {"date":"2021-11-17", "category":"prediction","value":21.21381},
    {"date":"2021-11-18", "category":"upper_95", "value":25.87625},
    {"date":"2021-11-18", "category":"lower_95", "value":22.32322},
    {"date":"2021-11-18", "category":"prediction","value":19.21381},
    {"date":"2021-11-19", "category":"upper_95", "value":26.87625},
    {"date":"2021-11-19", "category":"lower_95", "value":24.32322},
    {"date":"2021-11-19", "category":"prediction","value":25.21381},
    ...
]
```

My graph code:

```js
const Graph = () => {
    const config = {
         data,
         xField: "date",
         yField: "value",
         seriesField: "category",
         ...
    };
    
    return <Line {...config} />
};
```